# Run-Time Error '52121' - Code Fails on Only One Machine

Tags: vba, excel

In my `Workbook_Open` event, I activate a specific worksheet to ensure the user always opens on it. One user has an error message pop up when this portion of code tries to run:

`Run-Time Error '52121': Object Defined or Application Defined error`

I know the problem isn't with `EventsEnabled` because I tried that. If I had a guess, I would suspect that he is missing some sort of reference, or has corrupted software, but I don't even know where to begin figuring out either of those issues.

My Code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.EnableEvents = True 'this was added after I noticed his error
    Sheets("Control Panel").Activate 'it errors on this line
End Sub
```

This issue, again, only occurs on one machine.

Comment: Umm.. OK, replace that one machine.

Comment: @MartinJames Trust me, if I had the ability to make that decision I would.

Comment: Open the workbook on that machine.  Go to the tools pulldown in the VBA  IDE and select references.  See if anything is listed as MISSING.

Comment: Might be related to Permissions or Protection........is that User allowed to activate the given sheet??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent There aren't any permissions on the worksheet he's trying to open - good thought though.

Comment: @MatthewD I'll look into that when he comes back around, what would I do if something comes up 'missing'.

Answer (score 0):

To check for a missing reference, open the workbook on that machine. Go to the tools pulldown in the VBA IDE and select references. See if anything is listed as MISSING.

If there is a missing reference.
Look at the same reference on a machine that doesn't get the error. Look at the path of the reference and make sure it is right on the machine with the error. If it is wrong, select browse and look for the dll (or whatever) where the working machine shows it. If it is not there you can search the workstation for it. If it is not on the workstation you will have to find out what installs that library and get that installed on the workstation.

[image]